# htaccess redirect htm to html not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

i have an htaccess file that is about a mile long full of redirects, all working fine. but i cant get this one to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.html [R=301]
```

note that many of my URLs look like this:
http://www.domain.com/foo/bar/something/final.htm

where the number of subdirectory varies.

http://www.domain.com/foo/final.htm

also possible. or no subdirectory at all.

also, I cannot use

```
redirect 301
```

as the CMS's URL rewrite code won't work. all my redirects use `RewriteRule`

Thanks Mario

Comment: Are you sure none of your other million redirect rules are conflicting with this one, or that there is a rewrite condition set which is breaking it?

Comment: I just removed all my custom redirects and still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `/` in front of `$1`?

Comment: Yes. No luck. it seems to not pick up the rule itself.

Comment: it would be much easier to understand if you were posting the way your request ends up when you type something like `http://www.domain.com/foo/final.htm`

Comment: the request `http://www.domain.com/foo/final.htm` would come out the same.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. This works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.htm$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}l [R=301,L]
```